# Play evolution not loading 1.sql

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-evolutions

I'm running Play with Slick integration, Evolutions and an H2 database. When starting Play in dev mode and visiting localhost:9000 (I am using https) I am told database "default" needs evolution. However the script I have in conf/evolutions/default/1.sql is not display below. Rather it only shows:

```
1# --- Rev:1,Ups - da39a3e
```

However my script reads:

```
# --- ! Ups

create table "USERS" ("ID" VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "ACTION" VARCHAR);

# --- ! Downs

drop table "USERS";
```

Naturally all transactions on this table fail. Am I missing a bit of configuration?

Comment: Maybe it's `# --- !Ups` and `# --- !Downs` without the extra space?

Comment: @kris That's exactly what I found a moment ago!

Answer (score 2):

There must not be a space between the exclamation mark and the command:

```
# --- ! Ups
```

Wrong!

```
# --- !Ups
```

Right!